Disconnects and limited functionality messages when using DNS servers with DOH enabled
For some time now, two DNS servers with DOH enabled have been added to our company's local network.
Both servers are equipped with a valid SSL certificate issued by a trusted certificate authority.
However, if we use our Windows 11 clients with DOH enabled on DNS we encounter some anomalous behavior with Microsoft 365 components.
For example:

When started, the OneDrive client does not connect and remains in "connecting". If you try to unlink your company account and re-enter it you receive a proxy error 2606

A message appears on Teams saying that the program can be used but some features are limited due to communication problems with the servers

Outlook shows the inbox correctly but if you open a new message the text does not load in the window


Deactivating the DOH everything works again.
No other problems have been reported with other software or with normal web browsing
Both DNS have both Google and Cloudlfare public DNS as forwarders.
Both local DNS are running Bind9 updated to the latest version/build.
Use MS365 components with DOH enabled
